# jqgrid: How to get column index use custom formatter

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

**How to get column index use custom formatter.**

In column «Tax» i try use custom formatter. Need get column index value and row index value. I can get irow parameter irow = options.rowid but problem with getting icol parameter.

This is my example:

```
    var $grid = $("#grid");

    $grid.jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        height: 250,
        colNames:[' ', 'Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
        colModel:[
            {name: 'myac', width:80, fixed:true, frozen: true, sortable:false, resize:false, formatter:'actions',
            formatoptions:{keys:true}},
            {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int", frozen: true},
            {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date", frozen: true, editable: true},
            {name:'name',index:'name', width:100, editable: true, editable: true},
            {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float", editable: true},
            {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float", editable: true,

                 formatter: function(cellvalue, options) {
                    var id = options.rowId;
                    var col;

                    return id ?
                           '<span class="editable" data-id="' + id  + '" data-col="' + col + '">$' + cellvalue + '</span>' :
                           cellvalue;
                }

            },      
            {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float", editable: true},      
            {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false, editable: true}       
        ],
        rowNum:10,
        width:700,
        rowList:[10,20,30],
        pager: '#pager',
        sortname: 'invdate',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "date",
        shrinkToFit: false,
        rownumbers: true,
        caption: "Frozen Column with Group header and custom cell formatter",
        height: 'auto',
        frozen : true
    });

    var mydata = [
        {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
        {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
        {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
        {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
        {id:"5",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
        {id:"6",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
        {id:"7",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
        {id:"8",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
        {id:"9",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}
    ];


    for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++) $grid.jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata[i]);

    $grid.jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
      useColSpanStyle: true, 
      groupHeaders:[
        {startColumnName: 'amount', numberOfColumns: 3, titleText: '<em>Price</em>'},
      ] 
    });

    $grid.jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');
```

Use click cell event i can get col and row index.

```
    $grid.click(function(e) {
        var el = e.target;
            if (el.nodeName !== "TD") {
                el = $(el,this.rows).closest("td");
            }
        var iCol = parseInt($(el).index());
        var row = $(el,this.rows).closest("tr.jqgrow");
        var rowId = parseInt(row[0].id);

            alert ("rowId="+rowId+"; iCol="+iCol+";");
```

Comment: I don't think there is a faciity for that in the formatter, but the column index is the index in the colModel array. So the column index of myac is 0, and the column index of tax is 5.

Comment: @Sumit: because of usage of the `rownumbers: true` option `colModel` will be modified by jqGrid and the column `"rn"` will be inserted as the first column. So the column index of the `"tax"` column (the index of the column in `colModel`) will be 6.

Comment: @Oleg: is it possible get icol value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all please never use `addRowData` to make initial filling of jqGrid having `datatype: "local"`. Instead of that you can move the line with `var mydata = [...];` at the begining of your code and add `data: mydata` to the list of parameters of jqGrid.

Now about your main question: `options` parameter of the custom formatter have 4 properties:

- `grid` property - hold the string with represent the id of the grid. It's `"grid"` in your case.
- `pos` property - it's the index of the column in `colModel`. It will be 6 in your case. **So `options.pos` is the answer on your question**.
- `rowId` property - it's the rowid of the row which will be built now
- `colModel` property - it's the object which represent the item im `colModel` with the index `options.pos`.

Additionally jqGrid initialize `this` to the DOM element of the grid exactly like in case of calling any callbacks. So `$(this).jqGrid("getGridParam")` for example or `this.p` will get you the options of jqGrid.

Comment: Oleg, how to get parameters `iCol` use `cellattr: function( rowId, val, rowObject, cm, rdata) { var iCol;}`

Comment: @v2p: I'm not sere **why** you need `iCol`. It's more safe to use column name (the value of the `name` property of the corresponding column in the `colModel`. The problem is that the column index *could be changed* for example by usage of [columnChooser](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#column_chooser) or in case of usage `sortable: true` option of jqGrid (it allows the user to change the column orders by drag&drop of column headers). In general you can use `cm.name` to get the name of the column and you can find `iCol`  index in `this.p.colModel` array.

Comment: This is to my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597694/jqgrid-way-to-apply-custom-formatting-to-each-cell) please check. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is a callback function of jqgrid : onselectcell. In that you can get col index

```
onCellSelect : function(rowId, iCol, cellcontent,e) {
    var col = $("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
    var colName = col[iCol]['index'];

}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I need is an example of an event still uses this analogy onCellSelect my sample using click event. 
I would like to define icol on formation table use custom formatter